# How can I make VS Code's Secondary Sidebar open on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use secondary side bar in VS Code, but for some reason, VS Code always starts with secondary sidebar hidden.
How to change that? There is no setting for that and no hints provided in the internet that could help it.
I even tried to save workspace to see if this will keep the secondary side bar to stay open once I'll relaunch the VS Code- it will not.

Comment: you can look into tasks. You can for example automated opening terminals. I think opening side bars should be possible too https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_automating-terminals-with-tasks

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? Can you show a screenshot of what it looks like at startup and what you want it to look like?

Comment: @user Sure thing. This is how it looks like upon startup: https://i.imgur.com/GK62d3t.png  
And this is how I want it to look like: https://i.imgur.com/JUuR0P9.png  
Notice the panel on the right. This is a secondary bar.

Comment: Okay that's from the docker extension, right? Is that a panel like the terminal panel, output panel, and problems panel? Or is a different thing? (i.e. did it originally show up in the bottom area and you moved it to the right, or has it always been on the right?) If it's a panel in the same sense as terminal, output, and problems panels, see [Make vscode open the panel on start-up](/q/60109117)

Comment: No, it's vs code additional side panel, but yes - you can put there whatever. Including docker stuff. And yes - as far as I can remember it always was on the right side. And thank you for the link. Will take a look.

Comment: Please upvote people! https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191202

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab)use tasks to do this. Write a user tasks.json (to open this file in VS Code, you can run `Tasks: Open User Tasks` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), and in it, put a task that runs the command to toggle the secondary sidebar's visibility, and make it run on folder open. Ex.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Open secondary sidebar on folder open",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar}", // or focusAuxiliaryBar
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      },
      "hide": true,
    },
  ],
}
```

Credit for the original idea goes to Andrezza Souza. I've made some improvements to [what they originally wrote](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191202#issuecomment-1806959676).